# Apache Spark Group By (get First & Last values in Group)

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am running hadoop on a VM Cluster on my Schools cloud (honestly don't know the specifics). I'm using apache spark to talk to hadoop and  run my current code.

I've been trying to perform some aggregations on my data to find a total consumption value for an hour/day/month (ENERGY_READING column from data)

**CONSUMPTION.tsv** with some manipulations done already

```
+--------+-------------------+----+--------------+
|HOUSE_ID|CONDATE            |HOUR|ENERGY_READING|
+--------+-------------------+----+--------------+
|9       |2015-05-30 00:00:00|0   |11000.001444  |
|9       |2015-05-30 00:00:10|0   |11000.002888  |
|9       |2015-05-30 00:00:20|0   |11000.004332  |
|9       |2015-05-30 00:00:30|0   |11000.005776  |
|9       |2015-05-30 00:00:40|0   |11000.00722   |
|9       |2015-05-30 00:00:50|0   |11000.008664  |
|9       |2015-05-30 00:01:00|0   |11000.010108  |
|9       |2015-05-30 00:01:10|0   |11000.011552  |
|9       |2015-05-30 00:01:20|0   |11000.012996  |
|9       |2015-05-30 00:01:30|0   |11000.01444   |
|9       |2015-05-30 00:01:40|0   |11000.015884  |
|9       |2015-05-30 00:01:50|0   |11000.017328  |
|9       |2015-05-30 00:02:00|0   |11000.018772  |
|9       |2015-05-30 00:02:10|0   |11000.020216  |
|9       |2015-05-30 00:02:20|0   |11000.02166   |
|9       |2015-05-30 00:02:30|0   |11000.023104  |
|9       |2015-05-30 00:02:40|0   |11000.024548  |
|9       |2015-05-30 00:02:50|0   |11000.025992  |
|9       |2015-05-30 00:03:00|0   |11000.027436  |
|9       |2015-05-30 00:03:10|0   |11000.02888   |
+--------+-------------------+----+--------------+
```

**Java Class**

```
StructType schema = new StructType()
                .add("LOG_ID",IntegerType)
                .add("HOUSE_ID", IntegerType)
                .add("CONDATE", StringType)
                .add("ENERGY_READING", DoubleType)
                .add("FLAG", IntegerType);

        Dataset<Row> data = spark.read()
                .option("header", true)
                .option("delimiter", "\t")
                .option("mode","DROPMALFORMED")
                .schema(schema)
                .csv("hdfs://hd-master:9820/CONSUMPTION.tsv");

        data = data.withColumn("CONDATE", functions.to_timestamp(functions.col("CONDATE"),"yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS").cast(TimestampType));

        data = data.withColumn("HOUR", functions.hour(functions.col("CONDATE")));

        Dataset<Row> df = data.select("HOUSE_ID","CONDATE","HOUR","ENERGY_READING");
```

So the data I have increments every 10 seconds. I want to get the first and last values for each hour/day/month.

Essentially what I want is the first value of the day 11000.001444 and the last value lets just say 11000.01444 in this case. And then subtract the second from the first to get the total consumption for that hour/day/month.

Which would give me an output of

```
HOUSE_ID   CONDATE      HOUR       ENERGY_READING
  9        15-05-30      0              0.013
  9        15-05-30      1              ...
```

Comment: If you get the last value from each hour, you're doing 00:50 - 00:00, 01:50 - 01:00, etc, and you will miss the energy consumed during 00:50 to 01:00, 01:50 to 02:00, etc.  Instead, do you want to subtract value at 01:00 from value at 00:00? (i.e. 01:00 - 00:00) . In that case you will need the first value of every group.

Comment: I see what you're saying. So essentially the first value of each group would be subtracted from the previous group. So how would I go about writing such code?

Comment: yes, exactly. is that what you want to do instead?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly the same idea as what I was doing just  a different approach and would produce relatively the same result anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will group by minute and calculate consumption in that minute:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

Dataset<Row> df2 = df.groupBy(
    functions.col("HOUSE_ID"),
    functions.minute(col("CONDATE")).alias("minute")
).agg(
    functions.min("ENERGY_READING").alias("ENERGY_READING")
).withColumn(
    "LAG_ENERGY_READING",
    functions.lag(functions.col("ENERGY_READING"), 1).over(Window.partitionBy("HOUSE_ID").orderBy("minute"))
).withColumn(
    "consumption",
    functions.expr("ENERGY_READING - LAG_ENERGY_READING")
)
```

Comment: Operator '-' cannot be applied to 'org.apache.spark.sql.Column', 'org.apache.spark.sql.Column'

Comment: indeed it is :'(

Comment: yup, ill test it out. Give me a few minutes

Comment: no worries. Its a bit a bit of a process for me. Create a jar file, then transfer it over to the server and then running it and just now I forgot to print out the output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225949/discussion-between-mck-and-astronik).